# Where to get solid aluminum "battery" replacement cylinders?

Tags: battery

I once saw an ingenious setup while doing work for a state agency.  A contractor created a "black box" that contained a Canon camera in it for photographs that normally needed batteries in both it and the flash.  Instead they used solid aluminum cylinders that were crafted to be of identical size of AA and AAA batteries that then had nodes attached on one of the batteries so as to pass voltage on into the device through through a wire that was attached through a small hole drilled into the casing.

Ever since I saw this I realized just how much trouble I could save myself if I could find a handy source for these battery "replacements" and then just wire up the devices according to their electrical needs.  As a matter of fact, I've managed to do this for 9v rectangular batteries already with stock components.

I have quite a few devices that remain at fixed positions and so there's absolutely no reason to really use batteries in reality for them.

***Any idea on where I could obtain such battery "plugs" vs having to go to a machine shop to have them turned out?***

---

NOTE: *The thought has crossed my mind about using aluminum foil or foil tape and just turning existing batteries into conduits without having to get solid battery shaped replacements, but I worry about corrosion and various other problems with leakage, etc. I don't know if covering the battery nodes with electrical tape to insulate them first would be enough to keep the battery from eventually decomposing, etc., but I have reservations here...*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about modifying small electronics and not about home improvement.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I would strongly disagree since these are FOR the home and FOR improvement of home operations and such. So no, this is just as pertinent here as it would be re: modification of electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few names for them, but I don't know if there is an official name since they're a DIY solution. Search for AA dummy battery, AA placeholder battery, or AA fake battery, and you'll come up with a few places to buy them. They're commonly used in combination with AA Size 3.2V LiFePO4 rechargeable batteries.

Comment: Fantastic. I really liked the wood idea from @harper, but you've got it spot on. Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making them out of metal???   Make them out of wood.  Much easier to find a wood lathe than a metal lathe.

Just cut it about 2mm short on the active ends, predrill a small hole, sink 2 washers and a wood screw, and attach the wire between the washers. With screw, washers and wire, it's the same height as an AA.

Beware drywall and deck screws with insulating coatings.  Brass screws are a good choice.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! Not sure why I didn't think of wood to start with; guess I just had the original form on the brain! :)